# match a row with a comma or without comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get a comma separated list have each element surrounded by quotes, but I cannot capture the last line, which has no comma

```
 var input_value = 

'test,
 test,
 test'

input_value.replace(/(.*?),/gm, "\"$1\", ") //=> "test", 
                                                 "test", 
                                                 "test", 
                                                  test
```

How can I grab that last row and put quotes around him?

`/(.*?,)|(.*?)/gm` with the `|` operator is separating every letter and surrounding with quotes in the last line. How am I misusing it?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
input_value.replace(/(.+?)(,|$)/g, "\"$1\"$2 ")
                          ^^^^^
                 Match a comma , or the end-of-string $
```

Notice that you don't really need the `m` modifier, also using `(.+?)` instead of `(.*+)` prevents the regex from matching an empty string at the end of the string.

**EDIT:** I have updated the demo example below, so please check it. To see how `(.+?)` differs from `(.*?)` just edit the regular expression in the demo and see what happens, if you can't reason why this is happening, please let me know and I will explain further.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wZ6iQ9)

Comment: I think you are close, but maybe the replace string should be "\"$1\"$2" so that it doesn't put a comma on the last item. I didn't try it, just a thought.

Comment: @MacAnthony You are right, and there are a few more tweaks needed I, but I am waiting for feedback from the OP to edit accordingly.

Comment: This works very well. I notice it puts in line breaks between each value it puts in quotes. Why is this? Also, can you show another example of how `.+` differs from `.*`? Thank you so much.

Comment: @thomas No it doesn't put line breaks between each value it pus in quotes. I have edited my answer, please check edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, but this may work:

```
input_value.replace(/\b[^,]+/g, "\"$1\");
```

This would depend on your data structure though. If is just one word on each line followed by a comma, it'll work.

Comment: That will only work if the value you're matching starts with a word character, as they do in the example.  But the OP hasn't said what the real-world values will look like.  I'd get a ruling on that if I were you.

Comment: @AlanMoore - that's why I said this solution would depend on the data structure.